# Removing useless tag in XML from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following output in XML and i have problem on removing useless tags from the content. I have following XML values:

```
<Site EntityType="2" Identifier="CL">
  <Name Last="Rai"/>
  <Address/>
    <Contacts>
      <Contact>
        <Number/>
          </Contact>
      </Contacts>
</Site>
```

My question is how to remove useless tag from above XML using XSLT?

Desire output is like this:

```
<Site EntityType="2" Identifier="CL">
  <Name Last="Rai"/>    
</Site>
```

In above input `<Address/>`, `<Contacts>...</Contacts>` makes no sense so we are deleting those contents.

Comment: Can you me more precise as to what "useless" means, as even "empty" elements may have a use? For example, what if the element had attributes, like `<Specialties code="a" />`, or if the element only had "useless" children, like `<Specialties><Cake /></Specialties>`. Would these need to be removed too? Thank you!

Comment: I mean if it has useless children like <Specialties><Cake /></Specialties> OR if it has no any contain, means if it has just a tag like <Cake />.

Comment: please post your desired XML output also.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: What is XSLD?  Do you mean XSLT?

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this you should start off with the identity template which will copy across all existing nodes and attributes

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you only need to write templates for the nodes you wish to remove. Taking you definition of "useless" as "elements with no descendant text nodes (or processing instructions), and with no attributes and no descendant elements with attributes", then the template match would you like this

```
 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*/@*|descendant::text()[normalize-space()]|descendant::processing-instruction())]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*/@*|descendant::text()[normalize-space()]|descendant::processing-instruction())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if you use `xsl:strip-space`, you could adjust it slightly to this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*/@*|descendant::text()|descendant::processing-instruction())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am not able to delete whole <Contact> block from above XSLD.

Comment: This should delete the whole Contact element. Are you definitely using the XML you have shown in your question? Thank you.